# Array.reduce() not working when calculating product of numbers in an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, reduce

Good evening,

I got the following code in Javascript, where the user can choose to see the result of either adding up or calculate the product of all the numbers bigger than zero, up to the one the user chose (the question doesn't ask for input validation which is why I haven't added any verifying condition):

```
let number = readlineSync.question("Please enter an integer greater than 0: ");
let sumOrProd = readlineSync.question('Enter "s" to compute the sum, or "p" to compute the product. ');

let arraynumbers = [...Array(Number(number)+1).keys()];

let sumNumbers = (array) => array.reduce((acc,x)=> acc + x, 0);
let multNumbers = (array) => array.reduce((acc,x)=> acc * x, 1);

let userdecision = sumOrProd.toLowerCase() === 's' ? sumNumbers(arraynumbers) : multNumbers(arraynumbers);

console.log(userdecision);
```

`sumNumbers()` works fine, but `multNumbers()` always returns zero, and I can't see why (!?).
I have checked the documentation and other examples but I cannot see why it is not working.

Could anybody help me with this one?

Comment: Take a look at `arrayNumbers`, I'll bet it starts with `0`.

Comment: Your array likely has an item of index `0`. Anything multiplied by `0` will always return `0`.

Comment: *... all the numbers bigger than zero* — nothing in your code ensures that all the numbers are bigger than zero.

Comment: If you enter `5`, `arrayNumbers` will be `[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]`.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I completely missed that one!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You array arraynumbers starts with 0 just remove the first item:

```js
let number = 10;
let sumOrProd = 'p';
// Enter "s" to compute the sum, or "p" to compute the product. 

let arraynumbers = [...Array(Number(number)+1).keys()];
arraynumbers.shift();

let sumNumbers = array => array.reduce((acc,x)=> acc + x, 0);
let multNumbers = array => array.reduce((acc,x)=> acc * x, 1);

let userdecision = sumOrProd.toLowerCase() === 's' ? sumNumbers(arraynumbers) : multNumbers(arraynumbers);

console.log(userdecision);
```